# 'uplink' or 'interfaces'

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I wonder, which sentence fragment is better?

> 1. ... effectiveness of the **interface** failure detection
> 2. ... effectiveness of the **uplink** failure detection

Comment: It probably depends on the context - do you want to share a bit more? `Uplink` tends to be used with hardware/communications-specific interfaces. `Interface` is a more general word. But both words have some flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uplink implies one way communication, as in client to server, or ground station to satellite.  Interface implies two-way communication.  The better fragment would be determined by what "process'" failure is being detected.  Grammatically, either is as good as the other.